# List rows after specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a column in my database called "dob" of type datetime. How do I select all the rows after a specific DoB in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Simply put:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
dob > '1/21/2012'
```

Where 1/21/2012 is the date and you want all data, including that date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
dob BETWEEN '1/21/2012' AND '2/22/2012'
```

Use a between if you're selecting time between two dates

Comment: What rules apply with regard to the formatting of the date? I tested with "1/12/2012 13:14:33.000" and "1-12-2012 13:14:33.000" and both work.

Comment: The example is misleading. 12 is not the month! It is the day and it is in american format. It is in this format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
example `SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
dob > '1/13/2012`.
Now is clear that 13 is not month.

Comment: @Daniel when in doubt, it is better to specify the conversion as in `WHERE dob >= Convert(datetime, '2019-12-15' )`

Comment: For *MySQL*, you can use `NOW()` within your *SQL* statement, to get current `DateTime`. For more details, please refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to get all records from a table called `Table_One` with a datetime column called `date_value` that have happened in the past six months...

```
CREATE TABLE (
  date_value DATETIME
) 

SELCECT *
FROM Table_One
WHERE date_value > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate());
```

This gives a bit more dynamic of a solution.

Comment: What is DATEADD?